# Extending polymorphism in derived class from base class

Tags: c++

I have a base class `A`, another class `B` which is publicly derived from class 'A' and a main function:

```
#include <iostream>

class A  
{
public:  
    void add(int x,int y){std::cout<<x+y;}
};

class B:public A
{
public:
    void add(int *x,int *y){std::cout<<*x+*y;}
};

int main()
{
    B t;
    int p=5,q=6;
    t.add(p,q);
}
```

The above program fails to compile and I am able to understand the reason that `add` function in class A is hidden in class B.

My question, how do I achieve above task? I wan to add a function definition in derived class whose name is same as some function in base class. Parameter list will be different for the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to unhide the `add` methods from `A` in `B`, use:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::add;
    void add(int *x,int *y){std::cout<<*x+*y;}
};
```